# Powershell - Foreach with two sources

Tags: powershell, foreach

I've got two textfiles and I want to combine line1 from textfile 1 with line1 from textfile 2, line2 from textfile 1 with line2 from textfile 2

When I do a loop in a loop like

```
$profiles = Get-Content "C:\Scripts\profile.txt"
$links = Get-Content "C:\Scripts\links.txt"

Foreach ($profile in $profiles) {

    Foreach ($link in $links) {

    $profile
    $link

    }

}
```

I get this

```
File1Line1 - File2Line1
File1Line1 - File2Line2
File1Line1 - File2Line3
etc
```

How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option:

```
$profiles = Get-Content "C:\scripts\profile.txt"
$links = Get-Content "C:\scripts\links.txt"

$i=0
Foreach ($profile in $profiles)
  {
   "$Profile - $($links[$i++])"
  }
```

or, using a format string:

```
$i=0
Foreach ($profile in $profiles)
  {
   '{0} - {1}' -f $profile,$links[$i++]
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
For ($row = 0; $row -lt $profiles.Count; $row++) {
    $profiles[$row] + " - " + $links[$row]
    }
```